# bootstrap slider controls overlay browser pdf controls

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, pdf

I have an pdf inside a slider with controls to got to the next pdf on both sides. The problem is the right control overlaps with the pdf-controls of the browser, so I am not able to press the print out button.
[overlaying controls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sacCE.png)

```
<div class="item fullSize" id="inner-slider-item-0">  
<object class="center-block fullSize" data="ads/ad_pdfs/1.pdf" type="application/pdf"
internalinstanceid="75"> </object></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

viewer-toolbar - it's pdf controls block. 
It have CSS styles like:

```
viewer-toolbar {
    visibility: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Make z-index for your right button less than 3, and all will work fine:

```
.right-btn {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: In chrome this viewer toolbar has z-index of 1. If I set the z-index of the right btn to 0 its still overlapping. If i set it to -1 its completely hidden by the pdf.

Comment: ok. on the screen your button is above the toolbar, but it overlays it -> so i think height of the button is set to 100%, or something like it, isn't it?.Try to make it smaller - maybe that helps. Or try to make z-index of toolbar like 999 with css styles

Comment: I want to keep the height of the btn at 100% so how can I address the pdf toolbar to change the z-index?

Comment: u can make height 90%, and nobody will see that :) if this viewer-toolbar { z-index: 0; } - works...